# Multible jquery .load() methods not running concurrently in MVC 2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-ajax

In one of my aspx pages i have something like this in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        //  Jquery stuff

        loadStuff();

    });

    function loadStuff() {
       $('#result1').load({ source: url });
       $('#result2').load({ source: url });
       $('#result3').load({ source: url });
    };        
</script>
```

The idea being that as the page is being displayed these loads will populate the specified divs with results from different webservices as and when the info becomes available.
 
My problem is that this requests are being queued and being sent one at a time. However I want these to be sent at the same time and whichever returns first gets displayed first!
Also if I try to kick off another request while these divs are loading the request seems to get queued after the others. 
How do I make these requests concurrent instead of queued?
Thanks

Update:
I've noticed the AsyncController documentation on msdn.
Anyone tried thsi? Would this be the way to go?

Answer (score 2):

[Most web browsers have limit of 2 connections per server](http://www.oreillynet.com/xml/blog/2006/10/what_i_didnt_know_about_xhr.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could call the webservices in the action. That would allow multiple connections.
It would still be difficult to return multiple results when they arrive, but I think it can be done.